# assign custom function call to variable

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am quite new to Typo3 and Fluid, but I guess what I am after is quite basic.

**As an Analogy:** Twig can extended, so it is possible to create a custom function which can be used like that:

```
{% set id = uid() %}
<input id="{{ id }}" … /><label for="{{ id }}">…</label>
```

Is such a thing possible with Fluid? Do I need to install other extensions, or can that be done with basic fluid extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fluid you have two ways to achieve this:

1. Prepare the desired data in the controller and assign it to the view as variable.
2. [Create a custom viewhelper](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/6ac9833/doc/FLUID_CREATING_VIEWHELPERS.md) which contains the logic to build the desired data.

You can also combine these two and store the result of a viewhelper call in a variable using the `f:variable` viewhelper ([more usage examples](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/f852297c33c41aff10c0ca2eb8d9b699f6e2d1ae/src/ViewHelpers/VariableViewHelper.php#L26-L29)):

```
<f:variable name="myvariable">{acme:custom.viewhelper()}</f:variable>
```

In this specific case you can also install the VHS extension, the swiss army knife of Fluid, and use its [`UniqIdViewHelper`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/System/UniqIdViewHelper.html) Notice that you normally don't need this for forms since you bind them to (domain) objects you want to create/edit and let Extbase/Fluid handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for That. But is it possible to create something like `functions`, or: how can I assign the value of a view helper to a variable ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to mention the `f:variable` viewhelper.

Comment: THANKS… That was it…